# How to group items in ViewController to be shown and hidden?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a login ViewController where i've put loginTextField/passwdTextField/loginButton and, when the user is connected, i would like to reuse the same ViewController hiding login elements and showing other items such as ProfileButton, Logout and so on.

If i was in web development i would use DIVs to be shown/hidden ... is there something equivalent in Cocoa/Interface Builder?

Comment: You can create a outlet collection. http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/ Then use the performSelector method on the array to set hidden.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thank you very much! If you add your comment as answer i will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an IBOutlet collection like in this article...

http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/

This then gives you all the necessary controls in an array which you can either iterate through or use something like... `performSelector:` on all items in it.

Answer (score 1):

- Add two subviews [`UIView` elements] in your `storyboard` or `xib` related to 
  viewcontroller.
- In one view, add your login stuffs and in other view profile stuffs.
- Now create IBOutlets for both the views
- In `viewDidLoad` - hide profile view setHidden=YES and login view
  setHidden=NO
- After login successful - reverse this - hide login and
  display profile view